# What is an example of a problem that is in NP - P, but not NPC?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, np, p-vs-np

Assuming $P \neq NP$, I expected that $NP - P \subset NPC$, but from the diagram on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) it appears to not necessarily be true.

What is an example of a problem that is complex enough to be in $NP - P$, but doesn't allow every $NP$ problem to be reduced to it in polynomial time?

Comment: Are you looking for [NP-intermediate (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-intermediate)?

Comment: @hengxin Thanks, that's what I was looking for.